# "filesystem.squashfs failed" mounting error while installing Ubuntu 11.04 from bootable flash drive

Tags: system-installation, 11.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.04 from a bootable flash drive. A while after the installation starts, I get an error message:

> mount:mounting/dev/loop0 on//filesystem.squashfs failed: ... Ubuntu ::
> Error - Mounting /dev/loop0 On //filesystem.squashfs Failed ... Can
> not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on
> //filesystem.

This prevents me from installing Ubuntu 11.04 on my PC.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a corrupted `filesystem.squashfs` I would do an [MD5 checksum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the iso if it passes that then I would reinstall it to the flash drive and try again.

To do the MD5 with windows I recommend [WinMD5](http://www.winmd5.com/)